# Jquery - subtract src data from html encoded string

Tags: jquery, xml

I have an issue parsing an XML feed - The following code attempts to parse an XML feed and populate a page with news data.  The issue I have is that the description node is HTML encoded and I need to strip out the src of an img tag contained within it ( just one image tag is contained within each description node).

I have limited knowledge of regular expression - but I tried to use a filter approach to strip out the src code - but the below example doesn't work.

Any help would be gratefully received as I'm pulling my hair out with this one!

```
$(xml).find("item").each(function() {
    var i = $(xml).find("item").index(this);

    var imgStripSrc = $('item:eq(1) description', xml).filter(function() {
        return /(?: src=&quot;)(.+)(?:&quot;)/
    })

    if (i < 1) {
        var newsTitleOne = $('item:eq(0) title', xml).text();
        if (newsTitleOne.length > 40) {
            newsTitleOne = newsTitleOne.substring(0, 30) + "..";
        }
        $(".newsIOne .newsText .t").empty();
        $(".newsIOne .newsText .t").append(newsTitleOne);
    } else {
        var newsTitleGen = $('item:eq(' + i + ') title', xml).text();
        if (newsTitleGen.length > 80) {
            newsTitleGen = newsTitleGen.substring(0, 74) + "..";
        }
        var newsTitleLinkHid = $('item:eq(' + i + ') link', xml).text();
        var newsRow = $('<div class="newsRow"><a href="' + newsTitleLinkHid + '" target="_blank">' + newsTitleGen + '</a><img src=' + imgStripSrc + '/></div>');
        $(".newsRows").prepend(newsRow);
    }
});
```

XML example here - http://fb.mobilechilli.com/chilli_news_reviews/NewsReviews%20Build/tstXML.xml

Comment: Please also post a sample of the XML you are dealing with.

Comment: Could you attach the XML in question in your post or at pastebin.com ?

Comment: sure - XML item example here - http://fb.mobilechilli.com/chilli_news_reviews/NewsReviews%20Build/tstXML.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the fact that jQuery can build a DOM from an HTML string and therefore you do not need to fiddle with regexes *at all*. I rewrote your code:

```
$(".newsIOne .newsText .t").empty();
$(xml).find("item").each(function(i) {
    var html     = $( $("description", this).text() ), 
        imgsrc   = $("img:first", html).attr("src"),
        title    = $("title", this).text(),
        link     = $("link", this).text(),
        ellipsis = String.fromCharCode(8230);

    if (i == 0) {
        if (title.length > 40) {
            title = $.trim( title.substring(0, 30) ) + ellipsis;
        }
        $(".newsIOne .newsText .t").text(title);
    } else {
        if (title.length > 80) {
            title = $.trim( title.substring(0, 74) ) + ellipsis;
        }
        $(".newsRows").prepend(
            $('<div class="newsRow">')
            .append("<a>", {target: "_blank",  href: link, text: title});
            .append("<img>", {src: imgsrc});
        );
    }
});
```

Notes

- `this` always refers to the current element you are working on, so in the body of `each()` you do not have to juggle around those `$('item:eq(' + i + ') title', xml)`.
- `$(description, this).text()` fetches the HTML string, wrapping it in another `$()` creates a DOM from it. You can operate on that to find your `<img>`
- There is an actual ellipsis character (`"…"`), use it.
- Build HTML from concatenated strings at your own peril. I've used the convenient helper functions jQuery has built-in instead.
- The loop index is passed in as an argument from `each()`, no need to find/count it yourself.